# Find all min and max values in Column Python Panda Dataframe and save it in a new Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to find all the local min and maxima values in a column and save the whole row in a new dataframe.
See the example code below. I know we have groupy and likes. 
How do I do it in a proper way and create the cycle, which should increase by 1? Lastly only take the time of the minimum and they save it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

l = list(np.linspace(0,10,12))
data = [('time',l),
         ('A',[0,5,0.6,-4.8,-0.3,4.9,0.2,-4.7,0.5,5,0.1,-4.6]),
         ('B',[ 0,300,20,-280,-25,290,30,-270,40,300,-10,-260]),
         ]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(data))
print(df)

data_1 = [('cylce',[1,2,3]),
          ('delta_time',[2.727273,6.363636 ,10.000000]),
         ('A_max',[5,4.9,5]),
         ('A_min',[-4.8,-4.7,-4.6]),
         ('B_min',[-280,-270,-260]),
         ('B_max',[300,290,300]),
         ]
df_1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(data_1))

print(df_1)
```

Any help is much appreciated.